# Meaning of pull-out in education?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "pull-out" in this sentence? I can't figure out the exact meaning even though I looked up the dictionary.

> Schools that have adopted [**pull-out**](http://www.epi.org/publication/bp278/), team teaching, or block scheduling practices will only inaccurately be able to isolate individual teacher “effects” for evaluation, pay, or disciplinary purposes.

Comment: You'll need to provide more context for anyone to be able to tell you!

Comment: Try the Wikipedia entry on 'Gifted pull-out'.

Comment: A dictionary is not always the best resource you have at your disposal to look things up. Googling *pull-out in education* lead me to a number of sites with ready explanations.

Answer (score 1):

"Pull-Out" programs remove students from mainstream classrooms for a portion of the day in order to give them specialized instruction in particular areas - [ESL](http://sitemaker.umich.edu/356.hunemorder/pull-out_esl_), for example, or advanced areas of study for gifted students.

Pull-outs (also called "send-out" or "resource" programs) are an educational approach in which students are removed (or "pulled-out") from a heterogeneous (mixed-ability) classroom to spend a portion of their time with small groups of peers. Pull-outs tend to meet one to two hours per week.

Comment: Fantastic! I got the meaning of the word. Thank you so much.